# can not solve Cors error by using the required headers

Tags: php, api, rest, cors, backend

I am building a very simple app using php on the backend and react on the frontend. In my php backend I have a class and I have an endpoint "http://localhost/test-assignment/products/". If I access it directly through the browser or postman it works as it should but when I fetch it using axios on the frontend it doesn't work. I have used all the required headers but still no change :(

```
<?php 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

include_once '../../config/Database.php';
include_once '../../models/Product.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->connect();

$product = new Product($db);

$result = $product->read();

$num = $result->rowCount();

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {

$product->id = $_GET['id'];
$product->read_single();

$product_arr = array(
    'id' => $product->id,
    'sku' => $product->sku,
    'product_name' => $product->product_name,
    'size' => $product->size,
    'category_id' => $product->category_id,
    'height' => $product->height,
    'width' => $product->width,
    'length' => $product->length,
    'weight' => $product->weight
);

print_r(json_encode($product_arr));
} else {
    if($num > 0) {
        $products_arr = array();
        $products_arr['data'] = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        extract($row);

        $product_item = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'category_id' => $category_id,
            'product_name' => $product_name,
            'size' => $size,
            'height' => $height,
            'width' => $width,
            'length' => $length,
            'weight' => $weight
        );

    array_push($products_arr['data'], $product_item);    
    }

    echo json_encode($products_arr);
} else {
    echo json_encode(
        array('message' => 'No products Found')
    );
}

}
```

react file:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Header from './Header';
import Products from './products/Products';
import Footer from './Footer';
import AddProduct from './products/AddProduct';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() { 
    const getData = async () => {

        const options = {
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            }
          };

        const res = await axios.get('http://localhost/scandiweb-assignment-backend/api/products', options);
        console.log(res)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getData()
    }, [])

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Products} />
      <Route path="/addproduct" exact component={AddProduct} />
      <Footer />
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default App;
```

when I call the request to "http://localhost/scandiweb-assignment-backend/api/products" I get the following error

[image]

you can notice in the image, along with the CORS error I am also getting an error code of 301.

My xampp configuration:

[image]

Comment: There's no point in using `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the client. That's a reply header, not a request header.

Comment: yeah I know but even if I don't use it, it still doesn't solves the problem. I was just trying out everything to solve the error

Comment: I never meant to suggest that it has anything to do with the problem. It's totally ignored.

Comment: Barmar is right. Although, adding such a header in the client-side can actually cause more problems because then it's not in the list of allowed request headers (as per the Access-Control-Allow-Headers setting) which can then cause an additional CORS error. But anyway, it's very difficult to help you at the moment because you haven't actually told us specifically what error you're getting. "doesn't work" isn't an error message, and it's also not a useful problem statement either. We cannot fix an error if we don't know what it is.

Comment: Hey Guys, can you check again I have added more information to the question and have removed the options which are not required in the request. The error still persists if you need any more information please let me know :)

Comment: Looks like something is trying to redirect the request elsewhere.

Comment: yeah but it shouldn't happen because the url is working absolutely fine in postman or in the browser